# What's different/wrong with my MMULT function that my subroutine didn't have an issue with?

Tags: excel, vba, function, matrix

I'm a beginner to programming and vba.

Here's the code I wrote for a covariance matrix as a subroutine which went fine:

```
Sub CovarMMULT()

Dim Mean() As Double 'Declare array Mean
Dim Excess() As Double 'Declare array Excess
Dim ExcessTranspose() As Double 'Declare array ExcessTranspose
Dim Covar() As Double 'Declare array Covar

NoCol = Range("Returns").Columns.Count 'Count the number of columns from range name "Returns"
NoRow = Range("Returns").Rows.Count 'Count the number of rows from the range name "Returns"

ReDim Mean(NoCol - 1) As Double 'Re-declare size of array Mean

'Calculate average return

    For i = 0 To NoCol - 1
    Mean(i) = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("Returns").Columns(i + 1))
    Next i

ReDim Excess(NoRow - 1, NoCol - 1) As Double 'Re-declare size of array Excess Return

'Calculate excess return

    For Column = 0 To NoCol - 1

        For Row = 0 To NoRow - 1

        Excess(Row, Column) = Range("Returns").Cells(Row + 1, Column + 1) - Mean(Column)

        Next Row

    Next Column

ReDim ExcessTranspose(NoCol - 1, NoRow - 1) As Double 'Re-declare size of array Excess Return Transpose

'Calculate Excess return transpose divided by number of rows of Excess return

    For Column = 0 To NoRow - 1

        For Row = 0 To NoCol - 1

        ExcessTranspose(Row, Column) = Excess(Column, Row) / NoRow

        Next Row

    Next Column


ReDim Covar(NoCol - 1, NoCol - 1) As Double 'Re-declare Covariance Matrix array size

'Calculate the Covariance Matrix

    For ColumnVC = 0 To NoCol - 1
        For RowVC = 0 To NoCol - 1
            For Row = 0 To NoRow - 1

        Covar(RowVC, ColumnVC) = Covar(RowVC, ColumnVC) + ExcessTranspose(ColumnVC, Row) * Excess(Row, RowVC)

        Next Row
        Next RowVC
    Next ColumnVC


'Output all results onto sheet

Range("K14:P14").Value = Mean
Range("K17:P26").Value = Excess
Range("ExcessT").Value = ExcessTranspose
Range("K37:P42").Value = Covar


'Test out Application.mmult

Dim mmult As Variant

mmult = Application.mmult(ExcessTranspose, Excess)

Range("J58:O63").Value = mmult
```

And here's the code that my instructor used for building a function similar to the MMULT function:

```
Function My_MMult(a, b)

Dim ab()


a_row = a.Rows.Count
a_column = a.Columns.Count

b_row = b.Rows.Count
b_column = b.Columns.Count

ReDim ab(a_row, b_column)
For abrow = 1 To a_row
    For abcolumn = 1 To b_column
        For acolumn = 1 To a_column

            ab(abrow - 1, abcolumn - 1) = ab(abrow - 1, abcolumn - 1) + a(abrow, acolumn) * b(acolumn, abcolumn)
        Next acolumn
    Next abcolumn
Next abrow

My_MMult = ab()


End Function
```

For this same function, I tried doing this as a different approach of treating the 0th array position:

Function My_MMult(a, b)

```
Dim ab()


a_row = a.Rows.Count
a_column = a.Columns.Count

b_row = b.Rows.Count
b_column = b.Columns.Count

ReDim ab(a_row, b_column)
For abrow = 0 To a_row - 1
    For abcolumn = 0 To b_column - 1
        For acolumn = 0 To a_column - 1

            ab(abrow, abcolumn) = ab(abrow, abcolumn) + a(abrow, acolumn) * b(acolumn, abcolumn)
        Next acolumn
    Next abcolumn
Next abrow

My_MMult = ab()


End Function
```

My question is:

Why did my function fail to output the correct numbers but my subroutine worked fine?

Why can't I use "For abrow = 0 to a_row - 1 and have the ab(abrow, abcolumn)" instead of using "For abrow = 1 to a_row and having to use ab(abrow - 1, abcolumn - 1)"? etc...?

I tried debugging my function and it turned out the error took place inside the line:

```
ab(abrow, abcolumn) = ab(abrow, abcolumn) + a(abrow, acolumn) * b(acolumn, abcolumn)
```

What's wrong with it?

Finally, the reason I want to test this is because I found that when using For i = 1 to whateverstoredcountedvariable, it counts 0 as well and when doing the i-1 inside the subsequent equation, there will be an "empty array position" that didn't get utilized for storing numbers inside when i reaches the storedvariable without -1, Will this waste the computer's memory? If not by that much then nevermind, but I'm curious as to how I can make it 100% efficient by not including that extra empty array position into my code. So that's my purpose for bringing this up.

*Edit*
It worked! After I changed the function into:

```
Function My_MMult2(a, b)

Dim ab()


a_row = a.Rows.Count
a_column = a.Columns.Count

b_row = b.Rows.Count
b_column = b.Columns.Count

ReDim ab(a_row, b_column)
For abrow = 0 To a_row - 1
    For abcolumn = 0 To b_column - 1
        For acolumn = 0 To a_column - 1

            ab(abrow, abcolumn) = ab(abrow, abcolumn) + a(abrow + 1, acolumn + 1) * b(acolumn + 1, abcolumn + 1)
        Next acolumn
    Next abcolumn
Next abrow

My_MMult2 = ab()


End Function
```

Now I'm just wondering why the subroutine didn't have to go through with the + 1s.

Comment: In your function `My_MMult(a, b)` the parameter `a` and `b` are `Range` objects if the function is called as `=My_MMult(A1:C3, E1:G3)`. So `a(abrow, acolumn)` is equivalent to `a.Item(abrow, acolumn)`. There is no `Item` 0. The first `Item` is 1. So if `abrow` or `acolumn` is 0 it leads to an error.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Does that mean the `ExcessTranspose(ColumnVC, Row) * Excess(Row, RowVC)` from the subroutine were not "range objects"? What data type are they then?

Comment: Yes that does it mean. `ExcessTranspose` and `Excess` are `Double` arrays. And since `Option Base` is 0 by default, they are 0 based. Means the first index is 0 in all dimensions. So `ReDim Excess(NoRow - 1, NoCol - 1) As Double` means `ReDim Excess(0 to NoRow - 1, 0 to NoCol - 1) As Double`.

Comment: Got it! thanks a bunch!